# is it possible to select ,copy a text in pdf?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

i want to create a pdf page where i want to copy some text and paste in other document. i have gone through many pdf examples but i havent seen any app with selecting text in pdf.so i want to know whether it is possible or do i need to try with some other formats other than pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need CGPDF class for this purpose here is link this might help you

http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42

Comment: thanks prateek , this link helps me alot and i could get easily my requirement